# Nested Divs with Animated CSS Text overlay

Tags: html, css

I've searched through the site and not found anything with a solution exactly pertaining to my issue.  I'm creating a banner across a page at full width that will contain four different images that when you rollover will shade the image and display some text.  Problem that I'm having is that they either stack on top of one another or when that if fixed the hover only works on one of them.  Here is the code that I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/robertav/n9Le5rzj/1/embedded/result/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#wrapper {width:9999px;}

#school-container1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;}
#school-container2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;}

#school-container1 #school-box1:hover {
    opacity:1;}
#school-container2 #school-box2:hover {
    opacity:1;}

.SAD-text {
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 50px;}

#school-container1 #school-box1 {
    width:480px;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;}
#school-container2 #school-box2 {
    width:480px;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="school-container1">
    <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/A-D-copy320.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image1" title="image1" />
    <div id="school-box1">
      <p class="TEST 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="school-container2" >
    <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/mlsoc320-2.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image2" title="image2" />
    <div id="school-box2">
      <p class="SAD-text">TEXT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give Twitter bootstrap a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I drank some coffee and then figured out what was wrong. Like a sleep deprived goofball I forgot to make the hover dives relative to the containers they were in which was what was causing the problem.  Container needed to be defined as relative and the hover items needed to be absolute.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .school-wrapper {
        float: left;
    }

    .school-container {
        display: inline-block;
        position:relative;
    }

    .school-box1:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .school-box2:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .school-title {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-size: 24px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 190px;
    }

    .school-text {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

    .school-box1 {
        width: 480px;
        height: 320px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
        transition: all 0.7s ease;
    }

    .school-box2 {
        width: 480px;
        height: 320px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
        transition: all 0.7s ease;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="school-wrapper">
        <div class="school-container">
            <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/A-D-copy320.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image1" title="image1" />
                <div class="school-box1">
                    <p class="school-title">School of Hard Knocks</p>
                    <p class="school-text">Item 1 / Item 2 / item 3 / Item 4</p>
                </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="school-wrapper">

        <div class="school-container">
            <a href="http://yahoo.com">
                <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/mlsoc320-2.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image2" title="image2" />
                <div class="school-box2">
                    <p class="school-title">School of Silly String</p>
                    <p class="school-text">Item 1 / Item 2 / item 3 / Item 4</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I did find that the two school-boxes needed to be defined separately or they didn't work but this is a minor issue.  Thank you very much for the help and pushing me towards the right solution!

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
.school-container2 {
    position: relative;
}
```

When you use position: absolute (for the overlay) you need to pay attention to the parents of the element. The position: absolute attribute is always relative to the first position: relative; found in the parents of the elements. I hope that makes sense, if not, check this https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: On this one the images display correctly and the first image hover item showed but the second was nowhere to be found.

Comment: You're not implementing it right. This answer works, you just need to blend this snipped in your code, not replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, position relative is correct. But it will also make your life a bit easier to use some classes instead of ID's.

Markup with classes replacing some of the ID's

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="school-container">
        <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/A-D-copy320.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image1" title="image1" />
        <div class="school-box">
            <p class="TEST 2"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="school-container" >
        <img src="http://proservicesbburg.com/mlsoc320-2.jpg" width="480" height="320" alt="image2" title="image2" />
        <div class="school-box">
            <p class="SAD-text">TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Using classes so as not to be redundant.

```
.school-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    /* you shouldn't need float:left and inline-block */
}

.school-box:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.school-box {
    width:480px;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.SAD-text {
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This one put me back before square one, the images stacked and you can't really tell if both of the hovers worked at all.

Comment: Sorry, missed a quote in the code, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/carasin/cq1nwknh/